# Slide image with recyclerview in full screen android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sharedelementcallback

I have created a wallpaper app where I'm loading images from the firebase database in recyclerview. When I click on recyclerview item(image) that item's image URL is sent to the next activity and then that URL is loaded into imageView using glide.

I want to change this to something like [Image-Slider](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18X8HwRtv54WkAZoRwdku8_o0QN_zndWl/view). By clicking on the recyclerView item I want to show that image in full screen and slide from left or right(next or previous). But I don't know how to do that.

Here is my code.

```
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 3));
        adapter = new FeaturedAdapter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Wallpaper All");
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("dark").equalTo(true);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    FeaturedModel model = dataSnapshot1.getValue(FeaturedModel.class);
                    list.add(model);
                    
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Log.e("TAG_DATABASE_ERROR", databaseError.getMessage());

            }
        });
```

FeaturedAdapter.java

```
public class FeaturedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeaturedAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<FeaturedModel> featuredModels;

    public FeaturedAdapter(List<FeaturedModel> featuredModels) {
        this.featuredModels = featuredModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_image, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setData(featuredModels.get(position).getImageLink()
                , position,
                featuredModels.get(position).isPremium());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return featuredModels.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView imageView;
        private ImageView premiumImage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
            premiumImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.premium);

        }

        private void setData(final String url, final int position, boolean premium) {

            Glide.with(itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(imageView);

            if (premium) {

                premiumImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent setIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), PremiumViewActivity.class);
                        //setIntent.putExtra("title", url);
                        setIntent.putExtra("images", featuredModels.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImageLink());
                        setIntent.putExtra("id", featuredModels.get(position).getId());
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(setIntent);

                    }
                });


            } else {

                premiumImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent setIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), ViewActivity.class);
                        //setIntent.putExtra("title", url);
                        setIntent.putExtra("images", featuredModels.get(getAdapterPosition()).getImageLink());
                        setIntent.putExtra("id", featuredModels.get(position).getId());
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(setIntent);

                    }
                });

            }

        }

    }

}
```

ViewActivity

```
Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);

        Glide.with(this)
                .load(getIntent().getStringExtra("images"))
                .timeout(6000)
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(imageView);
setBackgroundWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setBackgroundImage();

            }
        });

}

 private void setBackgroundImage() {

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toasty.success(getApplicationContext(), "Set Wallpaper Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toasty.warning(this, "Wallpaper not load yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();
        }
        

    }
```

activity_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.PremiumViewActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="#00BCD4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottieSuccess"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:lottie_fileName="checked.json" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wallpaper_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/saveImage"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/set_as_wallpaper_btn"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setWallpaper"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/set_as_wallpaper_btn"
            android:minWidth="230dp"
            android:text="Set as wallpaper"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/favoritesBtn_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:button="@drawable/favourite_checkbox_selector" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/shareBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/share"
                android:contentDescription="@null" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ads_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/watch_ads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/set_as_wallpaper_btn"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/advertizing"
            android:paddingStart="50dp"
            android:paddingEnd="50dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            android:text="Watch Video Ad"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/watch_ads">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/unlock_withCoins"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/set_as_wallpaper_btn"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/diamond"
                android:paddingStart="50dp"
                android:paddingEnd="50dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@null"
                android:text="Unlock with diamonds"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/diamonds_tv"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Total Diamonds: 0"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

custom_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#fff"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/premium"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/diamond" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
Structure

MainActivity
    |
    | //Click button to open
    |
FragActivity
    |
    | //FrameLayout
    |
 Fragment
    |
    | //here is the recyclerView
    | //Open new Activity to view image 
    
ViewActivity
```

[Screen Recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10miP7tHv5tgvFBxIL0uLx6XAydz4QBfZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think you looking for this [Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18X8HwRtv54WkAZoRwdku8_o0QN_zndWl/view?usp=sharing) . If you are looking for this you should refer to ViewPager.

Comment: @Ramesh can you please provide me the link of library or sample code

Comment: There is no separate library for ViewPager. Please Go through this doc https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager/widget/ViewPager

Comment: Did you try using the view pager? Also, if you are comfortable only with recycler view, you can try using a Linear Layout with horizontal orientation.

Comment: No, I'm using ```GridLayoutManager```

Comment: I meant for the Full screen page, i have codebase where i worked with Linear Layout horizontal orientation. I can help with that if you need

Comment: @edison16029 I have updated my question and added structure. If ```LinearLayout``` works like a video (Sample video added above). So Plz help me.

Comment: Yeah, i am writing the answer.

Comment: @Marsad Refer to this link https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/12/android-image-slider-using-viewpager-example.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved by using `ViewPager` or `ViewPager2` in Android

First create an Adapter

ImageSwiperAdapter2.java

```
public class ImageSwiperAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageSwiperAdapter2.ImageSwiper> {

    private List<FeaturedModel> list;
    private Context context;

    public ImageSwiperAdapter2(List<FeaturedModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageSwiper onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.slidingimages,
                parent, false);

        return new ImageSwiper(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageSwiper holder, int position) {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);

        Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                .load(list.get(position).getImageLink())
                .listener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        holder.relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(holder.imageView);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    class ImageSwiper extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        private ImageView imageView;
        

        public ImageSwiper(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
          

        }


    }
}
```

In ViewActivity/SwiperActivity.java

```
public class SwiperActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager2 viewPager;
    private List<FeaturedModel> list;
    private ImageSwiperAdapter2 adapter2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swiper);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        
        final int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);

        Singleton singleton = Singleton.getInstance();

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list = singleton.getListSin();

        adapter2 = new ImageSwiperAdapter2(list, this);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter2);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                Toast.makeText(SwiperActivity.this, "Selected: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

You can pass the `list` and clicked item position in `FeaturedAdapter`.

In your `FeaturedAdapter's` `setData` method

```
private void setData(final String url, final int position, boolean premium) {
          Glide.with(itemView.getContext().getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(imageView);

            final Singleton a = Singleton.getInstance();
            a.setListSin(featuredModels);

            if (premium) {

                premiumImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent setIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), SwiperActivity.class);
                        
                        setIntent.putExtra("pos", position);
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(setIntent);
                        CustomIntent.customType(itemView.getContext(), "fadein-to-fadeout");



                    }
                });


            } else {

                premiumImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        
                        Intent setIntent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), SwiperActivity.class);
                        setIntent.putExtra("pos", position);
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(setIntent);
                        CustomIntent.customType(itemView.getContext(), "fadein-to-fadeout");

                    }
                });

            }

        }
```

slidingimages.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_swiper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SwiperActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layoutDirection="inherit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the ViewActivity must show all the images(when slided) it must contain the adapter with the set of image urls.
Instead of using an ImageView, use a RecyclerView in the ViewActivity and attach the adapter. In your code, do the following to make the recycler view horizontal and add slide functionality.

```
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    SnapHelper snapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Comment: Add you ViewActivity xml code if possible, so that i can edit my answer to suit your problem

Comment: I am recreating it, will answer soon

Comment: Use ViewpPager, its the best option you have out there.

Answer (score 0):

Few Days ago, I had been looking for similar requirement for showing slid-able image View.
This situation can be solved using `ViewPager` in Android.
You can use following Tutorials for building such Slide Image View using `ViewPager`

### Java Resources

1. [Blog Tutorial](https://www.androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/)
2. [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2FPDI99-as)

### Kotlin Resources

1. [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvlCKRpKVZs)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. For more information check [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)